# Mapbox GL Native doesn't build ubuntu18

Tags: opengl, cmake, mapbox, mapbox-gl, icu

I'm trying to build Mapbox GL Native using cmake .. so I cloned the repository from GitHub:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native.git
$ cd mapbox-gl-native
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ./
```

then it returns this with the erros:

```
CMake Error at node_modules/@mapbox/cmake-node-module/module.cmake:126 (add_library):
  Target "mbgl-node.abi-64" links to target "OpenGL::OpenGL" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  platform/node/CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_node_module)


CMake Error at node_modules/@mapbox/cmake-node-module/module.cmake:126 (add_library):
  Target "mbgl-node.abi-64" links to target "OpenGL::OpenGL" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  platform/node/CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_node_module)


CMake Error at node_modules/@mapbox/cmake-node-module/module.cmake:126 (add_library):
  Target "mbgl-node.abi-57" links to target "OpenGL::OpenGL" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  platform/node/CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_node_module)
```

I need heeeelp, I've been here trying to fix this but I don't know what could be the problem..

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your OpenGL library path installation is defined in your ENV path, 
you want to set up your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to your OpenGL installation path (you could set it in your top level CMakeList.txt).

Comment: thanks for the answer! , I just realized that my OpenGL library was not update... i just reinstalled it and It worked!